# Using arrays from other Subroutines in a new Subroutine within the same module

Tags: vba

I would like to use two arrays which haven been populated in two other subs, in a third sub. I simply want to divide each value of one array with the corresponding value from the other. `arr1`  and `arr` are the two already populated arrays from other subs.

when i call the subs `test1`, `test2` and `test3` from a sub in another module, i find that the arrays `aar1` and `arr2` are empty and get a type mismatch error for `p`

```
Option Explicit
    
Public arr2 As Variant
Public arr1 As Variant

Sub test1()
 
Dim arr1 As Variant
arr1 = ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D49")
Debug.Print arr1(24, 1) <-- not empty

End Sub


Sub test2()

Dim arr2 As Variant
arr2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E3:E49")
Debug.Print arr2(24, 1) <-- not empty

End Sub


Sub test3(arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant)

Dim p As Long
p = arr1(24, 1) / arr2(24, 1) `<-- Type mismatch since arr1 and arr2 are empty`


End Sub
```

Comment: One Sub by itself isn't much to go on: without more of the structure it's difficult to make suggestions besides "make the arrays globals" or "pass the arrays from the other sub"

Comment: @TimWilliams Edited the post to make it clear

Comment: In test1 and test2 don’t dim your arrays or you’ll create a separate copy which is just scoped to each sub

Comment: @TimWilliams that seems to solve it!